# Disable open ssh server without root elevation

Tags: linux, root, sshd

Is there a way to stop an ssh server without root elevation? Or just make others unable to connect to my computer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way (legitimate anyway) to do this without root elevation. If it is your computer why not just elevate to root and disable it there?

Answer (score 2):

@Caraxian is correct about stopping ssh server.

You may limit the users/groups that have access to ssh. Without knowledge of your distro, I will demonstrate with a CentOS/RHEL configuration:

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` you can use the `AllowUsers` or `AllowGroups` directives to explicitly allow certain users/groups to ssh. One easy way to do this is to create an ssh group and add users to that group (group id in example can be any unused group ID).

```
    # groupadd -g 2000 ssh
    # usermod -G johndoe ssh
```

After adding the users to the ssh group, append `AllowGroups ssh` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart sshd: `/etc/init.d/sshd restart` OR `service sshd restart`.

In the case where you don't want ssh to run at all on start-up:

```
    # chkconfig sshd off
```